# Polymer conditional class derived from child component

Tags: class, polymer, parent-child, web-component

I'm learning Polymer;

1. I can't get a conditional class name to appear in my tabs (parent) component. A 'active' class should be added to a `<li>` element depending on the 'selected' property of a child component.
2. I'm not really sure my way of communicating between parent and child component is right in the first place. It is working, but it doesn't feel right..

**My index.html file**

```
<link rel="import" href="components/tabs.html">
<link rel="import" href="components/tab.html">

<ikb-tabs>
    <ikb-tab heading="Tab #1">
        <p>Content of the first tab</p>
    </ikb-tab>
    <ikb-tab heading="Tab #2" selected>
        <p>Content of the second tab</p>
    </ikb-tab>
</ikb-tabs>
```

**My components/tabs.html file**

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<dom-module id="ikb-tabs">
    <template>
        <style>
            .active button {
                color: red;
            }
        </style>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{tabs}}">
                    <li>
                        <button on-tap="openTab">{{item.heading}}</button>
                    </li>
                </template>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <content></content>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'ikb-tabs',
            properties: {
                activeTab: Number
            },
            ready: function () {
                this.tabs = Polymer.dom(this).children;
            },
            openTab: function (e) {
                Polymer.dom(this).children.forEach(function (tab, index) {
                    tab.selected = index === e.model.index;
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

**My components/tab.html file**

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="ikb-tab" attributes="heading">
    <template>
        <template is="dom-if" if="{{selected}}">
            <div>
                <content></content>
            </div>
        </template>
    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'ikb-tab',
            properties: {
                heading: String,
                selected: {
                    type: Boolean
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: I recommend taking a look at [`iron-pages`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-pages) and [`paper-tabs`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-tabs).

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out myself, there were two main issues with my code:

**Updating an Array didn't trigger an update:**
Only adding, removing are replacing items in an Array triggers an update. I changed a property of an Object inside an Array. Polymer only checks the reference to that Object, that reference remained unchanged. So no change got triggered. Solution: update the Array with the set function (see code below).

**Computed classes need a special syntax:**
My class="{{getClassName(item.selected}}" wasn't adding any classes. I now know the correct syntax is class$="{{getClassName(item.selected)}}".

More info: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#native-binding

The simplified working code:

```
<dom-module id="ikb-tabs">
    <template>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{tabs}}">
                    <li class$="{{getClassName(item.selected)}}">

                        <button on-tap="openTab">{{item.heading}}</button>
                    </li>
                </template>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div>
            <content></content>
        </div>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'ikb-tabs',
            properties: {
                tabs: {
                    type: Array
                }
            },
            ready: function () {
                this.tabs = Polymer.dom(this).children;
            },
            openTab: function (e) {
                var self = this;

                this.tabs.forEach(function (tab, index) {
                    self.set('tabs.' + index + '.selected', index === e.model.index)
                });
            },
            getClassName: function (isSelected) {
                return isSelected ? 'active' : null;
            }
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```